# Creat axios interface and call from other files

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, redux-saga

I am trying to creat a service util to make http calls with axios from redux/saga.

But this function returns undefined evertime.

```
serviceutils.js

import axios from 'axios'

const apiV1 = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://google.com',
    timeout: 2000,
    headers: { 'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar' }
});
```

-

```
import apiV1 from './../Utils/Service.Utils'
saga.js
function* fetchdata() {
  yield apiV1.post("http://google.com")
}
```

Comment: 01-11 13:51:06.696  3946  4172 I ReactNativeJS: undefined
01-11 13:51:06.805  3946  4172 W ReactNativeJS: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
01-11 13:51:06.805  3946  4172 W ReactNativeJS: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: response

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, Axios operate in a promise based way so you have either do use async/await or promise's then/catch chain.

It is possible to have the Axios call in another file and consume it on a third but it does depends on above techniques. Please check the docs below:

https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 0):

```
you have need to return the function after done the execution or 
getting the response.

import apiV1 from './../Utils/Service.Utils'
saga.js
function* fetchdata() {
  return apiV1.post("http://google.com").then(function (response) {
    return response;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    return error;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with interceptor blocking response and returns undefined